# Ruby- delete h3 tags replace with sequence of chapter numbers

Tags: html, ruby, replace, tags

Ruby - Hi, I have max 200 html h3 headings in a html document. I am deleteing all, with characters between the two tags, using `x.gsub(/\<h3\>(.*)\<\/h3\>/, '<h3>Chapter </h3>')`. My problem is: I need to insert the individual chapter numbers 1, 2, 3 and so on. Is this possible using a hash or some other way?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this in wordpad and pasted it in. It read ok and posted, wow it has corrupted. it should be: Ruby - Hi, I have max 200 html h3 headings in a html document. I am deleteing all, with characters between the two tags, using x.gsub(/\<h3\>(.*)\<\/h3\>/, '<h3>Chapter </h3>'). My problem is: I need to insert the individual chapter numbers 1, 2, 3 and so on. Is this possible using a hash or some other way?

Comment: HTML comes after RUBY, why are you reversing here?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this...

```
# Establish a counter
i = 0
x.gsub( %r{<h3>(.+?)</h3>}i ){ |match| i+=1; "Chapter #{i}" }
```

The `%r{...}` is another way of defining a RegExp literal (`/.../`), it helps here, so you don't need to escape the slash; looks a bit cleaner...

Comment: Also, if you don't plan on using the previous content of the `h3` tag, you can just use `%r{<h3>.+?</h3>}i` and it will run a bit faster.